# QT: I've inherited from QTreeView. I've inherited from QStandardItem. How do i Style the items?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtreeview, model-view

My Google skills must be failing me today.

I've inherited from QTreeView to create a TreeView that stores a QStandardItemModel instead of a QAbstractItemModel. I have also inherited from QStandardItem to create a class to store my data in an item as is necessary.

I've successfully inserted my derived QStandardItem into my derived QTreeView's QStandardItemModel. Now the trouble is, I can't figure out how to style it. I know that QTreeView has a setStyleSheet(QString) member, but I can't seem to get it working. It may be as simple as I'm not styling the correct attribute. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

For clarity, here are my class defs.

```
class SurveyTreeItem : public QStandardItem
{
public:
    SurveyTreeItem();
    SurveyTreeItem( const QString & text );
    ~SurveyTreeItem();
};

class StandardItemModelTreeView : public QTreeView
{
    public:

    StandardItemModelTreeView(QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~StandardItemModelTreeView();

    QStandardItemModel* getStandardItemModel();
};
```

I've tried the following StyleSheets:

```
StandardTreeView::Item
{
font: 87 12pt 'Arial Black';
}

StandardTreeView::QStandardItem
{
font: 87 12pt 'Arial Black';
}

QTreeView::QStandardItem
{
font: 87 12pt 'Arial Black';
}

QTreeView::Item
{
font: 87 12pt 'Arial Black';
}

QTreeView::SurveyTreeItem
{
font: 87 12pt 'Arial Black';
}

StandardTreeView::SurveyTreeItem
{
font: 87 12pt 'Arial Black';
}
```

Comment: Please paste the string your passing to `setStyleSheet`.

Comment: @Kaleb, I'll paste it right now. I left it out initially because I knew that what I was entering was not working. I'll show everything I've tried.

Comment: I've actually tried styling it in the designer by using the parent, and I've converted all of those to one-liners in a QString(). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as it seems to work for my other components (like QPushButton and QTreeWidget, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it QTreeView::item should be the one. Bookmark [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/stylesheet-reference.html). That whole section is a pretty good read if you are doing this sort of thing

The font of the content of a `QTreeView` should be styled via the `QTreeview` itself e.g. `QTreeview {font-size: 20pt;}` and not via the style of the item

Comment: I tried this->setStyleSheet(QString("QTreeView::Item{font: 87 12pt 'Arial Black';}")); in the StandardTreeView with no success. I also tried making the i in "item" lower case like what you've listed. I will peruse the style sheet reference for some hints.

Comment: After looking at the stylesheet reference, I tried QTreeView::item::text and QTreeView::item:text and QTreeView::item.text and QTreeView::text with no success.

Comment: Actually playing after playing in the designer QTreeView {font: 20pt, 'Arial Black'} works, changing the item font. It looks like the view does render the item even though QTreeView::item {color: red} changes the color on the item

Comment: Awesome! Your last comment was the key. Thanks.